# Chamar função de outro arquivo, NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: Erro que está sendo gerado] Boa Tarde, gostaria de saber como puxar a função de um mini-programa para um programa em JS, exite o verificaNota.js que contem a função ***verificaNota***, gostaria de saber como puxar essa função no arquivo calculaNota.js

Quando ultilizo o import ele gera o seguinte erro

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: O arquivo `verificaNota.js` está expondo a função `verificaNota` através do [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)?

Comment: Não, como faço para expor ?

Comment: Veja o link do comentário anterior.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss segui os passos mas agora está gerando o erro anexado na imagem

Comment: Parece que no Node você utilizará o [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss utilizei o require e deu certo obg amigo, abs

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, transformei a função em uma variável e a nomeei assim `exports.verificaNota`, depois abri no segundo programa e inseri o seguinte comando `var nota = require('./verificaNota')` , agora para chamar  a função utilizo `nota.verificaNota(8,1)`